# Thunderbird display messages on top

Tags: thunderbird, mozilla

How do I make Thunderbird display newly received messages at the top of the inbox instead of the bottom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Thunderbird Inbox]

If you click on the date column as shown you can change the sort order.

Clicking again will change it back.  The sort column and order is remembered when you close Thuderbird so it should be the same the next time you open it.

Answer (score 2):

If you click on the header of the column you want to sort your messages by, this will sort them that way.

So to sort in date order, Click the date once to make them appear at the bottom and again to make them appear at the top. These changes apply only to that folder, so if, like me, you have 8 or 9 email accounts, you'll have to click a few times to get things how you want them.

Once done, this change sticks, until you click another column :)